# How to use the hint FULL for a count all in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, optimizer-hints

I'm new to the concept of using the hint optimizer in oracle and I would like to understand if I'm using the hint FULL properly

I have a query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.name='RandomName'
```

So let's say the result got me 12345

Now if I want to use the hint FULL , is that how it supposed to be written below ?

```
SELECT /*+ FULL(e) */ count(*) 
FROM MyTable e
 WHERE MyTable.name='RandomName'
```

The result is also 12345 is that normal?

Thank you

Comment: That appears correct.  Hints don't (well, barring bugs) change the results of a query, just the query plan.  You'd really want to see the query plan to determine whether the hint is correctly formatted in general.  Assuming there is an index on `name` and the first query used that index, the query plan for the second query should show you that the plan changed to a table scan.  If there was a problem with the hint, the plan wouldn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is how would specify a hint to Oracle. In this case, it should result in a Full Table Scan (not using any index you may have on the `name` column).

And the result will of course be the same. If using indexes changed the result, it would make them pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot , very appreciated , I was not sure at first because while consulting the documentation the use of hints is very similar to the use of comments ( usually comments aren't supposed to be executed if you know what I mean ) but now I'm starting to get a better idea . Again thanks a lot !